# All users been blocked after login

Tags: javascript, html, ajax, xml, dom

I am creating a login form which if the user tries 3 input login it will automatically block. but the problem is after 1 login only it already block. and All the users have been blocked. I want only after 3 times the username that i input will be blocked. Can someone help me?Thank you.

here is my code...

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<?php
    function p(){
    $xmldoc=new DOMDocument();
    $xmldoc->load('person.xml');
    $root=$xmldoc->documentElement;
    $data=$root->getElementsByTagName('user');

    $status="Blocked";

    if($data){
        $domelemupdate=[];
        foreach ($data as $domElement) {

            $domElement->childNodes->item(5)->textContent=$status;
        }
    }
    foreach ($domelemupdate as $domElement) {
        # code...
        $domElement->parentNode->replaceChild($domElement);
    }

    $xmldoc->save('person.xml');
}
    ?>

<html>
    <head>
    <body>
    </body>
    </head>
</html>
```

```
var ctr=0;        
        window.login = function(e)


    {

        if (document.frmlogin.login_username.value == "") 
        {
            alert("User name is not blank");
            return;
        }
        else if(document.frmlogin.login_pass.value == "")
        {
            alert("Password is not blank");
            return;
        }

        else
        {
            var xmlDoc;
            var x;    
            var txt = "";

            if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
                xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
            } else {    // IE 5/6
                xhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
            }

            xhttp.overrideMimeType('text/xml');

            xhttp.open("GET", "person.xml", false);
            xhttp.send(null);
            xmlDoc = xhttp.responseXML;


            var ktra=false;
            var xml=xmlDoc.childNodes[0];

            var name = xml.childNodes["username"];        
            var pass=xml.childNodes["password"];
            var status=xml.childNodes["status"];

            for(var i=0;i<xml.childNodes.length;i++){
                if(xml.childNodes[i].nodeName=="user"){
                    name = xml.childNodes[i].childNodes[3];
                    pass = xml.childNodes[i].childNodes[5];
                    status = xml.childNodes[i].childNodes[7];
                    position = xml.childNodes[i].childNodes[9];

                    if(name.textContent==frmlogin.login_username.value && pass.textContent==frmlogin.login_pass.value && status.textContent== "Active")
                    {
                        alert("Login Success!");

                }
            }
            if(ktra==false)
            {
                ctr+=1

                alert("Login Failed !!!" +ctr);

                if(ctr==3){

                    //alert("You are now Blocked!!!" );
                   x=p()
                   alert(x);



                }
            }
        }
    }

</script>
```

Whenever i call the function in my ctr==3 .If i run the program,if for example i try first login wrong username . after i click login the text easily update to block,.i want my counter 3 times before it will be block and i want the user that i input will be blocked only not all the users

Comment: You may use sessions to store on a per usrr base...

Comment: can u tell me how can i do it?

Answer (score 0):

You should be keeping track of the failed count either in a database, or write to the XML file an incremental count each time they fail to login with valid credentials..

Comment: how can i do it? :(